# Meteor requires sudo to run

Tags: macos, node.js, mongodb, meteor

Previously I was able to start Meteor 0.6.6.3 by simply running `mrt`.

Recently, Meteor 0.7.0.1 wont run properly unless I run it as root with `sudo mrt`. Environmental variables like `MONGO_URL` requires root to set it.

Any ideas what happened? I'm using Mountain Lion on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have run it with sudo once before. When you run it with sudo just once and a file is written the files become root files root user file so it needs more permissions to run and wont run 
ordinarily.

You might have run `sudo mrt` once it must have updated files for a package but they're now owned by root instead of your normal user.

I'm sure theres a terminal command to get it back but using Disk Utility and running 'Repair Disk Permissions' can also fix it (i think).

Comment: I've been able to resolve this with `sudo chown -R [yourusername] .` in the project's root directory before, but as Akshat suggests, whether this works or not depends on exactly what it is that you've done.